# item not supported on access a custom script,in zabbix_agent conf

Tags: zabbix

I have script which I am using from agent, it works good if only one or two machine. But I have 100 nodes so I kept the script in a shared location and changed the all agent conf file with this location.

That share location is an FTP server, still am getting error:
"no more connections can be made to this remote computer, the maximum number of connections has been reached".

How am I suppose to use a custom script in zabbix, I cant copy this to all the nodes every time.

Comment: That's not really a Zabbix question. You should probably invest time in a system management tool like Puppet, Chef, CFEngine, Bcfg2, Ansible, Salt... These all should help to some degree depending on your other needs.

Comment: Sorry, Just to confirm this means that in this scenario all changes must be done manually?

Comment: Not manually - by using some appropriate automation tool.